# Absorption of a simple random walker

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

A 1D random walk with absorbing barriers at 0 and N. Can we determine the mean time before an absorption event takes place at either barriers given that the probability to move left/right is $0.5$ everywhere except at barriers, where then the probability to be absorbed in next jump is $p$ and the probability to jump away from the barrier is $q?$  where $p>q$.

In the simpler case where p and q are also equal to 0.5, the mean time is known, $t_a=a(N-a)$ where $a$ is the starting site of the walker and 0 and N are the positions of the two barriers.

Comment: There is a standard renewal theory technique way to get this mean: given the transition probability matrix $P$, the mean time $u(x)$ to hit any set $A$ starting from $x$ satisfies $((P-I)u)(x)=-1$ for $x \not \in A$ and $u(x)=0$ for $x \in A$. I haven't done the calculation to see whether this system of linear equations can be solved in closed form in your example. This system comes from the total expectation formula, conditioning on all possible values of the process at the second step, and the Markov property.

Comment: Do you mean $t_a = a(N-a)$ when there is no reflection at the boundaries, i.e., $p=1, q=0$?

Comment: @user929304 In that case, I don't think $t_a = a(N-a)$. Can you explain how you got it?

Comment: I think you two are talking past each other a little bit. What is $p_{N-1,N}$ in your illustration? (Presumably it is $0.5$.) And what is it in your actual problem? (I'm not sure, but it sounds like it is either $p$ or $0.5p$.) Or another way to phrase the question: is $p_{N-1,N-1}$ zero in your problem or not?

Comment: @Ian the case Im interested to learn about is $p_{N-1,N}=p>0.5$. The cited result is valid for $p_{N-1,N}=0.5$.

Comment: Alright, so $p_{N-1,N-1}$ and $p_{1,1}$ are zero then. That pins down the transition probability matrix. With that in hand you can try what I suggested. Why not try it numerically and see if you can see some kind of pattern?

Comment: I understand that you are asking for the mean time $t_a$ to hit the state $\partial$ for the Markov chain on the state space $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}\cup\{\partial\}$ starting from some state $a$ in $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$, with transition probabilities $\frac12$ for the transitions $k\to k-1$ and $k\to k+1$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant N-1$, $q=1-p$ for the transitions $0\to1$ and $N\to N-1$, and $p$ for the transitions $0\to\partial$ and $1\to\partial$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Did thanks for getting back to me. That s almost it, if the absorbing barriers are at $0$ and $N$ then we have: $q$ for $N-1 \to N-2$ and $p$ for $N-1 \to N$ and similarly $q$ for $1 \to 2$ and $p$ for $1 \to 0.$ With $p>q$, whereas all other transitions (between neighbouring sites) happen with probability $1/2$.

Comment: The usual Markov decomposition after one step yields $t_1=1+qt_2$, $t_{N-1}=1+qt_{N-2}$, and, for every $2\leqslant k\leqslant N-2$, $t_k=1+\frac12t_{k-1}+\frac12t_{k+1}$. These conditions for $2\leqslant k\leqslant N-2$ imply that $t_k=uk+v-k^2$ for some $(u,v)$ independent of $k$. The conditions on $t_1$ and $t_{N-1}$ imply that $u+v-1=1+q(2u+v-4)$ and $u(N-1)+v-(N-1)^2=1+q(u(N-2)+v-(N-2)^2)$. The solution of this system is $u=N$ and $v=((q/p)-1)(N-2)$, hence $t_a=a(N-a)+((q/p)-1)(N-2)$ for every $1\leqslant a\leqslant N-1$.

Comment: @Did thanks a lot, this is very intuitive! I have to admit I m very new to this kind of calculations, but out of curiosity: in such RW scenarios, is the "frequency" of visiting a certain site ever of interest? E.g. does it make sense to ask in the above situation, what the frequency of visiting the sites $N-1$ and $1$ is in a n-step walk? Is it trivially related to $t_a$?

Comment: Generally speaking, computations in "finite horizon" (until some fixed time n) are more cumbersome than in "infinite horizon" (until absorption or on every nonnegative time). The computations I presented deal with the infinite horizon.

Comment: @Did I just wanted to ask if you'd recommend any books on the theory of RWs and markov chains, one that also focuses on the finite and infinite case analyses. If it helps, I'm more interested to learn practical methods (even if approximative) rather than learning the formal proofs in the field (not to by any means diminish from their merit and importance). Additionally, could I write up here an answer based on your comment, for future readers?

Comment: "could I write up here an answer based on your comment" Absolutely, excellent idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many interesting points have already been pointed out in the comments, amongst others by user [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did), which in essence already contain an answer to the post, so I decided to write them up here as an answer for future readers.

---

Given that the absorbing barriers are placed at $0$ and $N,$ we have the following important transition probabilities: $N-1\to N-2$ happens with probability $q$ and $N-1\to N$ with probability $p$ ($q+p=1$), similarly, the transition $1\to 2$ happens with probability $q$ and $1\to 0$ with probability $p.$ All remaining transitions happen with probability $1/2.$ Thus we are only modifying the behaviour at the barriers, and asking how favouring absorption influences the mean time before an absorption event takes place.

Now we perform a Markov decomposition after one step of the walk, this yields the mean time before absorption $t_1 = 1+qt_2$ starting the walk from $1,$ $t_{N-1}=1+qt_{N-2}$ starting from $N-1$ and for every other starting point $2\leqslant k \leqslant N-2 ,$ the corresponding mean time is $t_k = 1+\frac{1}{2}(t_{k-1}+t_{k+1}).$ The latter condition implies that $t_k$ ought to take the form of 
$$t_k=uk+v-k^2\tag{1}$$ 
for some couple $(u,v)$ independent of $k.$ Moreover, the former conditions on $t_1$ and $t_{N-1}$ imply the following relations: 
$$
\begin{align}
u+v-1 =& 1+q(2u+v-4) \tag{2} \\
u(N-1)+v-(N-1)^2 =& 1+q(u(N-2)+v-(N-2)^2). \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
The equations $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ together form a system of equation that can be solved, yielding: $$u=N\qquad v=((q/p)-1)(N-2)$$ hence the modified mean time before absorption is given by:

$$
t_a = a(N-a) + ((q/p)-1)(N-2)
$$
for every starting point $a$ such that $1\leqslant a\leqslant N-1.$